# Two different UICollectionViewCells, switch between them in a UISegmentedController

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol, uicollectionviewcell

I wonder which's the easiest way to have two different UICollectionViewCells-identifiers in the same UICollectionView? I've got an UISegmentedController that I want to switch between to different styles of UICollectionViewCells.. Where to implement which code. I've got an PatternViewCell for the first Cell but how do i do with the other? Please advice!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two collection view cell prototypes registered for a single cell class for a single collection view with a single data source.

First, in your storyboard, set `Cell1` as a reuse identifier for the first cell prototype and `Cell2` for the second one. Both of them should have `PatternViewCell` class.

Then, on changing value of your segmented control you reload your collection view:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Bind this action to your segmented control for the `Value Changed` event.

Then in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method you can choose a reuse identifier depending on selected index.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *identifier = nil;
    if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        identifier = @"Cell1";
    } else {
        identifier = @"Cell2";
    }

    PatternViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //configure cell
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Cant make it work, would you like to make an example? I've been struggling with this for days now, cant figure it out! I'v got an custombuild segmented controller so dont know if it's because of that one..

Comment: @MartinBorstrand I've created a sample project: https://github.com/nikitashytyk/TestSegment

Comment: Great Thank you! Will look it up now and try it! Will resubmit later! Thanks again!

Comment: @MartinBorstrand Did this code/sample help you to achieve the result you needed?

Comment: Not as I were thinking, but I could use it for another purpose! But i did so that I created two collectionviews in the same controller and then set the second one to be hidden while the first one to be shown. It's working but dont know it's a good way.. Thanks for the help! @NikitaShytyk